# datetime format in Quarters

Tags: pandas

I am reading in a text file that includes a column of quarters in the format:

```
201301
201302
201303
201304
201401
```

I convert the index of the data frame with

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%Y%m')
```

How can I convert the index to quarters of the form

```
2013Q1
2013Q2
2013Q3
2013Q4
2014Q1
```

Comment: that format specification would treat the 01 02 03 04 as months, not quarters

Comment: When reading the data, is 201301 an integer or text value.  Do you want the result to be a text string or a Pandas period object?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def convert_to_quarter(d):
    ts = pd.Timestamp(pd.to_datetime(d,format='%Y%m'))
    return "{}Q{}".format(ts.year, ts.quarter)

convert_to_quarter('201302')  # Returns '2013Q1'
convert_to_quarter('201304')  # Returns '2013Q2'
```